# URI is not registered javafx intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, compiler-errors, fxml

I'm making an app with javafx. The gui is described using fxml. in this fxml I have the following line:

```
BorderPane prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="830.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.
```

Due to the compilation error I had to copy file to the `target` folder. So the problem is that everything is allrigt in the file that is in the project folder and being copyed to `target` the string is red and "uri is not registered". In the another `.fxml` file that decribes another window this error even in the file that is in project folder. In my opinion this cause an error during compilation: `javafx.fxml.LoadException:` What's wrong?